# SQL location from a known point query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database with the following table

```
int - id
float 2,6 - long
float 2,6 - lat
int - radius
```

I want to create a SQL query which returns the ID & Distance from a given location(long & lat)

I found the following piece of code which works:

```
SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) *
cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * 
sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers 
HAVING distance < 25 ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

I want to alter this query to return only the rows where the computed length is smaller the radius (a column i my table)
replacing the 25 with the radius doesn't work.
Is there a way to achieve that without using two SQL queries ?

Comment: please explain with an example.. your question is not clear

Answer (score 1):

problem is occured because the result `distance` is in **float** and radius is an **integer** datatype so you need to CAST radius as float. try below

```
SELECT id, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) *
cos( radians( lng ) - radians(-122) ) + sin( radians(37) ) * 
sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM markers 
HAVING distance < CAST (radius AS float) ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

**HAPPY TO HELP :)**